# Cклоняется ли  фамилия Якимук?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Здравствуйте!
Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли  фамилия Якимук? Когда муж заполняет какие-либо документы, пишет: "Якимука Александра". Мне кажется, что это неверно.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это верно! Мужская фамилия Якимук склоняется, женская - нет.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем вы видите неправильность? Заглавные буквы не использует?
Фамилия, естественно, склоняется. 
Вот ваша (если вы взяли его фамилию), склонятся не будет.

Comment: звучит это не совсем красиво

Comment: Вот с этого места, если можно, поподробнее. ;)
Дело в том, что неблагозвучность фамилии пои изменении по падежам - пожалуй единственный аргумент за её "несклоняемость" или выбор особенного варианта склонения. Но это должно быть явным и очевидным  неблагозвучием. Как, например, при склонении фамилии Скобец рекомендуется выбирать вариант Скобеца, Скобецу и т.д.  против общих правил беглой гласной в суффиксе Ц.  
А что такого неприличного в варианте "Александра Якимука"?